# Inverting shift register

Tags: dac, inverter, shift-register

I am trying to invert the output of a shift register using an open-collector TTL inverter with 33K pull-up resistors.

The inverter works fine when input=HIGH, but when the input is LOW, the output is LOW. I tried using some bypass capacitors at the inputs but that didn't seem to work. See included figure.

The square oscillations seem to be coming from my clock somehow.

Any suggestions for getting output to be high when input = low?

[image]

Here is my schematic (constructing a 4-bit successive approx circuit). 
[image]

I realize that there are a bunch of double-negatives, but that is because I only have NAND gates and inverters to work with, and my flip-flops come with ~CLR and ~PRE inputs instead of S and R.

Comment: Please include a schematic of your circuit.

Comment: Your text says you used 33k pull-up resistors. But your schematic shows no resistors. Without a schematic that shows your actual circuit, it's **unclear what you're asking**.

Answer (score 1):

For TTL, 33kilohms is way too high!

Try 3.3 kilohms or lower - or use the CMOS equivalent (74HC or 74HCT) of each TTL chip.

The critical parameter in the datasheet (page 6-5 in ["The TTL Data Book"](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Data-Book-Design-Engineers/dp/090404727X/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8) 1980 edition) is Ioh (high level output current) which is a measure of how well that open collector will turn off, or how low its leakage is when off..

And for an open-collector inverter (7405) it is specified at ... 250ua max. 74LS is better at 100 ua, but that will still drop 3.3V across your 33K resistor, regardless of any load from inputs connected to it.

This may look pathetically high for a transistor's leakage; but remember these transistors were tuned for high speed (in terms of the time) not low leakage.

For comparison, the 74HC05 has Ioh=5ua max (dropping about 0.16V) neglecting leakage from any connected inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Routine debug with another pullup resistor can validate impedance and function of output node. If it does not pull-up, something is pulling it down.